# Update parent style when child has data-state or aria-checked changed in React + Styled Components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

There is label that has a button inside of it like:

```
<MyLabel htmlFor='xx' onClick={() => onChange}>
    <MyButton id='xx' {...rest} />
    Check it!
</MyLabel>
```

In Developer Tool's Elements it looks like this:

```
<label for="xx">
    <button type="button" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" data-state="unchecked" value="on" id="xx">
    </button>
    Check it!
</label>
```

Here are the components:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import * as Checkbox from '@radix-ui/react-checkbox';

export const StyledCheckboxRoot = styled(Checkbox.Root)`
  button {
    all: unset;
  }
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
`;

const MyLabel = styled.label`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  & > button {
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
`;
```

When the button is clicked, there are toggles between `aria-checked="false"` and `aria-checked="true"`, also between `data-state="unchecked"` and `data-state="checked"`.

Is there a way to update the style of the parent, the `label` in this case when those actions are happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rerender parent element. When this properties on children changed, parent doesn't rerender.
Add state to parent, pass setState to children and use it on click.